# Is there a way to read the contents on the network tab in any Browser under Developer Console using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, testing, video, pytest

I am trying to test the Video Quality based on the bitrates that are being streamed on my own websites, Using Python, Is there any way to read the contents in the Network Tab under Developer Console?

Comment: What is the goal of this? I mean how does knowing the _"contents in the Network Tab"_ help you to test video quality? Maybe if you tell us what you want from these Network Tabs, if lucky, there could be another way to get same information with Python alone

Comment: Actually, the Video Bitrates are shown in the segments when a video is loading or streaming on my website which is what I want to capture to test the Video Quality